# Autowire list of Beans in Spring an get their names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some Spring Beans of a specific type but with different names:

```
@Bean public Car audi() { .. }
@Bean public Car mercedes() { .. }
@Bean public Car honda() { .. }
```

Now I can autowire all of them with:

```
@Autowired List<Car> cars;
```

With this I get all Car-objects.

Is it possible to get also the bean names somehow?

Comment: What do you want to use the name for? Maybe it would be enough to identify the bean by its properties (fields of Car)?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Car>` instead of a `List<Car>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M. Deinums comment had the correct solution

```
@Autowired Map<String, Car> carsAndNames;
```